# WordPress; Display different content template based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop

I want to take the basic WordPress loop and in the place where it makes the call for the content template, I want to run an if else statement that pulls in a different template part based on the category. I know I can make a bunch of copies of archive.php, but why do that for each and every single category you want to use?

So I tried this code, but it just pulled in the archive template in each case:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

        if ( is_category( 'my-category-slug' )) {
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive' );
        }

endwhile;
```

So can I even run an if else statement like this within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), you need to make sure that your code is in the right php file. Check up [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png). In your case you need to modify category.php, you can use archive.php for this if you delete all category*.php files.

Comment: There is no category.php file in this theme. Only archive.php. It's in the right file.

Comment: if it is executing and you only get the 'template-parts/content-archive.php' each time and never have 'template-parts/content-single.php' doesn't that mean that you don't have archive pages with the category slug "my-category-slug"? or youre not looping the good results (maybe not using WP_Query with args )?